# what's the diff. between rospy.Time(0) and rospy.Time.now()?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rospy.Time(0) 这是什么含义? 跟rospy.Time.now() 有啥区别？
Hi, I'm learning tf and time at [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/tf%20and%20Time%20%28Python%29)

and I'm confused about the different between `rospy.Time(0)` and  `rospy.Time.now()`

Could you explain it for me?

**Thank you very much!!**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243179/what%27s-the-diff.-between-rospy.time(0)-and-rospy.time.now()?/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-09-06

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm confused about the different between `rospy.Time(0)` and `rospy.Time.now()`

`rospy.Time.now()` just returns the current 'wall clock time' (or the simulated clock, depending on whether you have a [Clock server](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock) running).

`rospy.Time(0)` constructs a `Time` instance that has special significance in TF contexts: it will cause `lookupTransform(..)` and friends to return the *latest available data* for a specific transform, instead of the data at a *specific point in time*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12